# Php associative array function that finds duplicated by id value and non duplicate values made in to array

Tags: php, arrays

If there are 2 posts for 3 pages, the function that fetches the posts, will return Array of [6] like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [post_text] => Test 3:30
            [post_id] => 46
            [concrete_id] => 5c3f55b5ebb084c078c92d13
            [post_data_start] => 2019-02-06 15:31:00
            [post_type] => II
            [page_id] => 7
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [post_text] => Test 3:30
            [post_id] => 46
            [concrete_id] => fus98f67a9
            [post_data_start] => 2019-02-06 15:31:00
            [post_type] => II
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [post_text] => Test 3:30
            [post_id] => 46
            [concrete_id] => 5c3f55b5ebb084c078c94c0
            [post_data_start] => 2019-02-06 15:31:00
            [post_type] => II
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [post_text] => test
            [post_id] => 43
            [concrete_id] => 5c3f55b5ebb084c078c92d13
            [post_data_start] => 2019-02-06 17:31:00
            [post_type] => II
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [post_text] => test
            [post_id] => 43
            [concrete_id] => fus98f67a9
            [post_data_start] => 2019-02-06 17:31:00
            [post_type] => II
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [post_text] => test
            [post_id] => 43
            [concrete_id] => 5c581a33ebb084c078ceb6cc
            [post_data_start] => 2019-02-06 17:31:00
            [post_type] => II
        )

)
```

In my cURL call I have to pass the `concrete_id` as an array (because it costs 10cents a call), in this case I have to make 6 cURL calls, but I could only do 2 calls passing `concrete_id` as Array. The API I use works that way (but the question has nothing to do with the API)

I want to get an array with unique id, but with array of the different values (or just `concrete_id` would do):

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [post_text] => Test 3:30
            [post_id] => 46
            [concrete_id] => 
                Array( 
                    [0] => 5c3f55b5ebb084c078c92d13
                    [1] => fus98f67a9
                    [2] => 5c3f55b5ebb084c078c94c0
                )
            [post_data_start] => 2019-02-06 15:31:00
            [post_type] => II
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [post_text] => test
            [post_id] => 43
            [concrete_id] => 
                Array(
                    [0] => 5c3f55b5ebb084c078c92d13
                    [1] => fus98f67a9
                    [2] => 5c3f55b5ebb084c078c94c0
                )
            [post_data_start] => 2019-02-06 17:31:00
            [post_type] => II
        )
)
```

this is the best I could come up with, but my brain is hurting:

```
$tmpposts=$posts;
            foreach($posts as $k=>$post){
                foreach($tmpposts as $k2=>$post2){
                    if($post['post_id']==$post2['post_id']){
                        $post2['concrete_id']=array($post2['concrete_id']);

                        array_push($post2['concrete_id'],$post['concrete_id']);
                        $array[]=$post2;
                        array_splice($array,$k);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may reduce the array with simple `for-loop`. Consider the follow:

```
$arr = []; // example just with "id" and "concrete_id" but you can add all other data
$arr[] = array("id" => 46, "concrete_id" => "5c3f55b5ebb084c078c92d13");
$arr[] = array("id" => 46, "concrete_id" => "fus98f67a9");
$arr[] = array("id" => 46, "concrete_id" => "5c3f55b5ebb084c078c94c0");
$arr[] = array("id" => 43, "concrete_id" => "5c3f55b5ebb084c078c92d13");
$arr[] = array("id" => 43, "concrete_id" => "fus98f67a9");

foreach($arr as $e) {
    if (!isset($ans[$e["id"]])) {
        $ans[$e["id"]] = $e; // element doesn't exist set first time
        $ans[$e["id"]]["concrete_id"] = [$e["concrete_id"]]; // make the concrete_id as array with 1 element
    } else { // the id already set just append the concrete_id
        $ans[$e["id"]]["concrete_id"][] = $e["concrete_id"];
    }
}
```

You can use [`array_values`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) if you don't want the `id` as keys in the result as: `$ans = array_values($ans);`

Comment: Mah man! This works perfectly. The id in my array is called post_id and yes I used the array_values.